# How to change image when user press keybaord arrow keys using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this gallery. I need to change the image when the user will press the arrow keys after the modal popup. left arrow key to change the image in the left and the right arrow key for right. I'm pretty new to javascript so if you can help me it would be great. Please see the code snippet in full page.

```js
function openModal() {
            document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
          }
          function closeModal() {
            document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
          }
          var slideIndex = 1;
          showSlides(slideIndex);
          function plusSlides(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
          }
          function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
          }
          function showSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
            if (n > slides.length) {
              slideIndex = 1
            }
            if (n < 1) {
              slideIndex = slides.length
            }
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
          }
```

```css
    .modal {
      width: 58%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      position: fixed;
      display: none;
      background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
      margin-left: 300px;
      max-width: 779px;
      min-width: 779px;
    }


    .modal-content {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
    }

    .mySlides {
      display: none;
    }
   .mySlides {
      display: none;
    }

    .cursor {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .cursor {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .prev {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      top: -149px;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -50px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      left: -10%;
    }

    .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      top: -149px;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -50px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      left: 600px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="main-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x200" width="250" height="164"
            onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x210" width="250" height="164"
            onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
          <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x200" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
          </div>
          <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x210" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
          </div>
          <a class="prev" id="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To detect arrow key press you can add keydown eventlistener and check for keycode.
Key code for left arrow key is 37 and for right arrow key is 39.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    // Left arrow key is pressed
  } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    // Right arrow key is pressed
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Tanvi Naik is right, with his solution you can easily create a working gallery:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {

    // Left arrow key is pressed
    plusSlides(-1)

  } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {

    // Right arrow key is pressed
    plusSlides(1)
  }
});
```

Full snippet

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}


/* ADDED THIS: */
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {

    // Left arrow key is pressed
    plusSlides(-1)

  } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {

    // Right arrow key is pressed
    plusSlides(1)
  }
});
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 58%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  margin-left: 300px;
  max-width: 779px;
  min-width: 779px;
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -149px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  left: -10%;
}

.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -149px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  left: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x200" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x210" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x200" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x210" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
        </div>
        <a class="prev" id="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
```